# I cant add any library

Tags: android-studio, gradle

when I try to add any library then I have simple this error:

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

I only add a RecyclerView.
my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abbasmehdipur.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-

rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
        implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

finally I found problem!!! just a bad proxy setting.